# yiiSkeletonApp error 404 on all links

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I downloaded yiiSkeletonApp from https://github.com/travisstroud/yiiSkeletonApp

managed to get `localhost/dev` working but when i click on login / register i get an Error 404.

the login url and register url's are `http://localhost/dev/login` and `http://localhost/dev/user/create`

in my **protectd/config/main.php** i have this..

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

also the files **protected/views/site/login.php** and **protected/views/user/create.php** do exist

here is the error message

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
```

folder content:

```
localhost/dev/
- assets/
- css/
- images/
- protected/
- themes/
- yii/
- facebook-channel.php
- index.php
- index-test.php
- README.md
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? specify the error message.

Comment: Can you please mention, the file path to your directory ? i.e D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\index.php

Comment: im on a mac. `Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/dev/protected/config/` like i said. localhost/dev/ works.

Comment: try accessing this url from localhost, http://localhost/dev/index.php/site/login and let me know.

Comment: yup works. something wrong with `urlManager` ?

Comment: I have included an answer below.

Comment: Thank You @dev1234! It worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You site is configured to use hard coded path's it seems. so its referring to the wrong paths.

try accessing this url from localhost,

```
localhost/dev/index.php/site/login

localhost/dev/index.php/site/user/create
```

There is no issue with urlManager. You can refer to this link to understand URL Manager of yii.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: i have this `'url'=>array('/site/login'),` as the link. i want to hide `index.php`

Comment: only way to do is to play with .htaccess file. Please have a look at this wiki article. it works :) http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/